CloudSQL proxy seeing many "read: connection reset by peer" errors
We have a service running on GKE that calling cloud SQL DB(MySQL) via cloudSQL proxy.
We have seeing a lot of below errors on the cloudSQL proxy side:
"2024/04/29 18:36:48 Reading data from local connection on 127.0.0.1:3306 had error: read tcp 127.0.0.1:3306->127.0.0.1:59378: read: connection reset by peer"

And seeing a lot of below errors on the cloud SQL DB side:
"2024-04-29T19:00:48.577436Z 19109994 [Note] Aborted connection 19109994 to db: 'xxx' user: 'xxx' host: 'cloudsqlproxy~10.20.5.2' (Got an error writing communication packets)"


Could we get some help understand what caused these errors?
Any recommendations to reduce such errors?


The application connecting to the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy is dropping the connection. It is unlikely the problem is an issue between the auth proxy and Google Cloud SQL. The problem is most likely an application design issue. Review how the application manages database connections and if there is any code that consumes the CPU for long periods of time causing CPU starvation of the TCP stack.
